# .Net Core Dynamically Restrict Create/Deletes based

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authorization, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a context which authorizes access to Db Resource based on the Access Token. Which uses entityframework plus to dynamically filter my dataset. The Code looks something like this:

```
    public AstootContext(DbContextOptions<AstootContext> options, IUserAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(options)
    {
        this._authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.SetContextFilters();
    }

    protected virtual void SetContextFilters()
    {
        var claimsIdentity = this._authenticationManager.GetClaimsIdentity();
        var userId = 1;
        this.Filter<Conversation>(c => c.Where(x => x.EmployeeUserId == userId || x.EmployerUserId == userId));
    }
```

This takes care of handling Get requests, and updates(assuming they have to retrieve the entity first).

I would like to be able to prevent a user from creating a resource they do not have access rights to.

For instance.
      A user cannot create a conversation between 2 users where 1 of them is not themself.

What can I do to filter creation/deletion of resources?

Comment: This is something which should be taken care by application code. You can not handle this at database or DAL layer. Application should check if conversation being created has the logged in user part of it and show the error message if logged in user is not part of it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks for your response, but I need it to work that way because I am working on a framework in which will create a secure context based on the authorization rules.  I think I’ll just end up overriding save changes to inverse the filter logic to create a validator then I maybe I’ll only have to worry about the cache

Comment: I ended up solving this by overriding save changes to have a validator inside of it. It's a lot of code to post so if anybody needs it just comment and I'll post it